# Google Sheets - Arrayformula referencing other sheets equals broken formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a spreadsheet with a few sheets I reference with `=INDEX`. The code I use below works fine when I Paste as Formula to all the cells in a column.

```
=INDEX(DATABASE!A:A, MATCH('SMS FINAL'!C2:C, DATABASE!C:C, 1))
```

The code I am trying to use has ArrayFormula so that I only have to type the formula in once:

```
=ArrayFormula(
 IF(ROW(E:E)=1,"Company",
  IF(ISBLANK(E:E),"",
  INDEX(DATABASE!B:B, 
  MATCH('SMS FINAL'!C:C, DATABASE!C:C, 1)
))))
```

This breaks the column and only leaves the "Company" in the header row. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try it like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Company";
  IF(ISBLANK(E:E), ,
  INDEX(DATABASE!B:B, 
  MATCH('SMS FINAL'!C:C, DATABASE!C:C, 0)))})
```

or like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Company";
  IF(ISBLANK(E2:E), ,
  INDEX(DATABASE!B:B, 
  MATCH('SMS FINAL'!C:C, DATABASE!C:C, 0)))})
```

Comment: Did not work. Only repeats the first company of the reference sheet (DATABASE). It seems like it is in a loop that only pulls out the first entry DATABASE!C:C (after having a 1 at the end to indicate there is a header row).

Comment: I can only privately due to it having PII in it.

I am trying this code: '=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(C2:C250,DATABASE!$C$2:$C$365,2,false))' but it is taking forever to load and is making my laptop's fans go crazy.

I need to make sure the ARRAYFORMULA (A) can continue past the set # of rows (ex C2:C), (B) doesn't take forever to load, (C) I need to add an IFERROR function to show blank cells if nothing is there, or the data doesn't exist in column C (row hasn't been created yet)